# How does the setOnCheckedChangeListener method work in JAVA?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning to code with JAVA and am currently in Android Studio learning how to use Switch buttons. I simply want to understand what all the parameters do inside the setOnCheckedChanged function do and why it is written the way it is.

setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)

What do all of these things mean and how are they working in the background?

1. setOnCheckedChangeListener
2. **new** keyword
3. CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener (why is it all together)
4. @Override (what is this overriding?)
5. **onCheckedChanged** (why can't this be renamed to something else?)

I truly appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Hi, @Andres if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi @Remon, I do appreciate you taking the time to go over my question. My issue is that I can get most of the code structure. It's understanding _why_ something is supposed to go there is the problem I'm encountering. Google searches haven't been very helpful either, nor YT videos. I keep coming across the same tutorials on how you can use it, but they don't explain _why_ to use it and what each item is doing. I have some experience in JS and the syntax there makes sense to me because I can see what each element is doing to the bigger picture. I work well with analogies. Thnx for your help

Comment: Hi @Andres, you can refer to the Java documentation to get a clear understanding of the keywords like "new". Please form the question more specific, so that other users can answer the question also more precisely. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - setOnCheckedChangeListener is a method that sets a listener that listens for events on your UI component(event source).

2 - the new keyword is used to create a new object.

```java
new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
```

what this part do is: create an anonymous class that implements the 
`OnCheckedChangeListener` interface and override the 
`onCheckedChanged()` method
3 - CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener: the OnCheckedListener is an inner class inside CompoundButton that's why it should be called using the outer class.

4 - overriding is: declaring your specific behavior for a method that's inherited from the parent class.

my advise to you..you have a lot to learn about OOP first in order to understand all of this.

let me know if you need tutorials that explain those topics. but you will find many if you try to Google

Comment: I would appreciate any tutorials or anything that could help me understand these topics better. I like analogies to make sense of things and I like understanding the "why" of many things especially with code. I want to understand what each thing is doing and how/why it affects other elements around it. Thanks again for your help/advice.

Comment: if you like books, I would recommend ("head first java") it has very good reviews. if you like video tutorials more, you can search for the cave of programming. good luck